# HTML5 Map with geo tagged points

Tags: jquery, html, sencha-touch, mapping, kendo-ui

I am looking for an HTML5 based tool I can use to display a map on the screen which can be zoomed, paned, etc (Google Maps) and on this map I want to display a circle in a specific location when a button is pushed on a web page?

Any HTML5 compatible frameworks would be recommended?  Or would you recommend JQuery?  I know I can do this with JQuery and write some of the scripting myself.  I know google has an API I can use to do some of this as well.

What I am wondering is that are there any frameworks out there that can simplify this in a more elegant way?  Recommendations?

Preferably, I am looking for compatibility with desktop browser and iPad.  It is ok if the support for desktop browsers is only with the latest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if its commercial or not (Google Maps is not free for non-public facing).

I would recommend looking at Nokia's solution (http://developer.here.com/) which has excellent support for mobile and desktop, and a very liberal license (if you email them they'll tell you can use the Base plan for commercial, even though their site says otherwise).  They have good documentation - drawing that circle is trivial, and generally its easy to use.

Comment: It's a public facing site, but it's a private company.  I am not clear on google's restrictions in this regard.

Comment: I like google, because I can see user value in integrating street view in the future...

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple solution, you can consider iMap's [HTML5 map builder software](http://www.imapbuilder.com/html5-mapping/), which let you create HTML5 maps quickly using their pre-built HTML5 Map templates.

They already have templates for all the continents and major countries (e.g. USA, Canada, UK, etc).  The software provide tools for adding pushpin, mouse-over speech boxes, and set zooming and color of state / county etc.   The map works on all devices including PC, Mac, iPhone, iPad, Android phones, etc

If you need street-level maps then it won't work as the HTML5 maps shows map border lines only. You may then consider the Google Map editor instead.